# Quais são as linguagens de programação que a Google utiliza

Tags: google-maps, google

Bem gostaria de saber qual é a linguagem de programação que a barra de pesquisa foi criada, e nos aplicativos do google, em qual linguagem foram criadas?

Não encontrei de forma acessível essas informações

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, isso é uma perguntar bem complicada... Mas vamos lá.

Meu nome é Ramom e faço Ciência da Computação na Universidade Federal de Pernambuco. Tenho alguns amigos que foram trabalhar na Google, Facebook, Microsoft. Segundo eles, essas empresas são bem flexíveis quanto a qual linguagem você irá trabalhar. Digamos que você tenha mais afinidade em Python do que a C++, então eles irão te incentivar a trabalhar com a linguagem que você mais se sente confortável em trabalhar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Imagem tirada do site: http://programadorbr.com/blog/qual-a-linguagem-utilizada-pelas-grandes-empresas-de-tecnologia/

A barra de pesquisa em si foi criada como qualquer outra barra de um site comum, porém o algoritmo de pesquisa e sua linguagem é uma receita como da Coca-Cola etc... Ou seja, eles nunca irão divulgar. Como está em constante mudança, atualmente eles usam um mix de linguagens para melhorar o desempenho, velocidade, assertividade na pesquisa. Python e C++ são algumas delas, são linguagens poderosíssimas quando o assunto é desempenho e velocidade. 
Nos aplicativos digo o mesmo... Mas creio que Java é uma das mais usadas quando o assunto é Mobile Development.